# How to call CMD with utf8 arguments from perl?

Tags: windows, perl, unicode, cmd, character-encoding

How to call CMD with utf8 arguments from perl without messing the argument's characters?

One of the things I've tried is to convert a string of unicode characters to its unicode character codes then use `system($cmd)`:

```
use utf8;

`chcp 65001`;
binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)";
$string = "αω";
$converted_string = convert_to_unicode_code($string);
    # gets $converted_string = '\x{03B1}\x{03C9}'
$cmd = 'program "'.$converted_string.'"';
    # $cmd's value is: program "\x{03B1}\x{03C9}"
system($cmd);

sub convert_to_unicode_code {
    my $input = shift;
    $input =~ s/(.)/"\\x{" . (sprintf "%04X", ord $1) . "}"/eg;
    return $input;
}
```

Actually this solution doesn't work as expected and calls `program "\x{03B1}\x{03C9}"` instead of `program "αω"`.

Comment: Why do you need these escapes? Are you trying to create a specific output format? Depending on your goals, there may already be a module and we don't have to implement this by hand.

Comment: So to be clear, you want the string `"αω"` converted into the string consisting of 16 ASCII characters `"\x{03B1}\x{03C9}"`? May I ask what you need this for? If you want a string in Perl's format, does [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) not work for you? But if it's not Perl, then I'd suggest *not* to use `Data::Dumper` - using a module specific to the format you want to create would be much better.

Comment: I have simplified the example. I need this in order to send this to Windows CMD later.

Comment: Could you show the code you are using to "send this to Windows CMD" and explain/show the expected behavior, and how it's currently failing?

Comment: (BTW, in regards to my comment above, I should have written `'\x{03B1}\x{03C9}'` to stay in the correct Perl notation of single-quoted strings not interpolating escape sequences. That you used double quotes in your question is also confusing.)

Comment: @ikegami I'm still a tiny bit doubtful, since under `utf8`, `"αω" eq "\x{03B1}\x{03C9}"`, so I wonder if there is more background to the question, e.g. I'd be curious to know what went wrong when the OP tried `print "αω";`.

Comment: @haukex: That string is two characters long. Encoded as UTF-8 it happens to be two two-byte character encodings. There is no ASCII involved at all. To generate what I imagine you meant by *"the string consisting of 16 ASCII characters"* you would use single quotes: `'\x{03B1}\x{03C9}'`. I'm sorry if this appear finicky, but many people are still confused by Unicode in Perl, and I feel that no amount of words can be too many.

Comment: @Omar, Decode inputs, encode outputs. You'd need to encode. To encode, you can use [`encode`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode). But you have to use the encoding for system calls, not the encoding used by the console. There are two version of each Windows system calls that deals with text. The "A" version of the calls expect text to be encoded according to the Active Code Page (`"cp".Win32::GetACP()`). The "W" version of the calls expect text to be encoded using UTF-16le. Only the latter gives access to the full range of Unicode chars.

Comment: `mkdir` calls `CreateDirectoryA`, so it won't do the trick. But [Win32::Unicode::Dir](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::Unicode::Dir)'s `mkdirW` calls `CreateDircetoryW` (and handles the encoding for you). This is definitely the way to go to create directories.

Comment: If you want to spawn an external program, I don't have a solution handy. Both `system` and Win32::Process use `CreateProcessA`, but you need access to `CreateProcessW`.

Comment: You'll probably have to use [Win32::API](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::API) to expose `CreateProcessW`.

Comment: cmd.exe is a Unicode application, so there should be no immediate problem there, at least not for the command line as long as cmd.exe is executed via `CreateProcessW` with the command line as a UTF-16 string. There could be subsequent issues related to how CMD uses its attached console's output codepage (i.e. `GetConsoleOutputCP`), basically as the process locale, whenever its internal commands read from and write to pipes or disk files. UTF-8 can be used via `chcp.com 65001`, but with care and only temporarily because the console itself (not CMD) has many bugs in how it handles UTF-8.

Comment: @Borodin I completely agree, and I did correct myself in a later comment. It was just somewhat too late to edit the original comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Win32::Unicode](http://p3rl.org/Win32::Unicode).

αω.bat

```
@echo hiαω
```

so48996757.pl

```
use utf8;
use Win32::Unicode::Process qw(systemW);

system 'chcp 65001';
systemW 'αω';
```

Comment: If "αω.bat" is a UTF-8 file, then it's the batch script itself that should call `chcp.com 65001`, and only temporarily to read in UTF-8 string literals from the .bat file. It needs to save the previous codepage and restore it as soon as possible because the console has many bugs associated with setting the input and output codepages to 65001.

Comment: For example, with codepage 65001, input read via `ReadFile` or `ReadConsoleA` will be limited to 7-bit ASCII; `WriteFile` and `WriteConsoleA` will report the wrong number of bytes written prior to Windows 8; and even `WriteConsoleW` will fail for non-ASCII text if a raster font is selected in the console.

Comment: I'm getting `Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Win32::Unicode'.` when I try to install Win32::Unicode. I am using Windows 10 and Strawberry Perl v5.26.1.1

Comment: I see some test failures, too. They are not relevant to the `systemW` subroutine. If you wish, you can skip/disable the tests and force an installation: `cpanm -nv Win32::Unicode`